# Jquery setTimeout constantly calls function multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery code that uses ajax method to call a PHP file and checks if there is any update. 
If there is no update the timer function kicks in and constantly check the PHP file for an update every 5 seconds.
I have manage to get the function working but the time laps is too fast. Even I have changed the interval speed to different parameter  it does not show any change.
My Jquery Code  is:

```
function CheckCallerID(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "code/PHPFILE.php",
        data: "",                 
        success: function(data) {
            //ajax returns Below HTML CODE
            $('#caller').html(data);

            if($('#newaddressdetails').html().length==0){ 
                var timmer = setTimeout(CheckCallerID(),50000); 
            }else{
                SaveAddress();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PHP FILE RETURN VALUE for True
`<div id="newcustomer">Update Found</div>`

PHP FILE RETURN VALUE for False 
`<div id="newcustomer"></div>`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Close - you need to omit the `()` when passing a function to be called:

```
var timmer = setTimeout(CheckCallerID,50000);
```

When you keep the `()` in there - it executes the function immediately.

Comment: Yes, setTimeout requires the name of a function. If the `()` is still here, the funciton will execute and setTimeout will use the return value of the function as the name of the function to call after the execution of the timeout.

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer